SwiftUI ScrollView will not scroll to bottom when keyboard appears
I am developing a view in SwiftUI that has a ScrollView of messages and below that a text input field at the bottom of the page.
When the input field is pressed, the keyboard properly appears and the input bar moves up with the keyboard as expected. However, I can't get the messages to remain anchored at the bottom of the scrollview as the keyboard appears, which results in 1-2 messages to be covered by the keyboard and text input field.
What I ideally want is to have the messages scroll up in unison with the keyboard animation like in the Messages app in iOS.
I've tried to solve this problem with a few different approaches I have found on Stack, Reddit, YouTube, with ChatGPT, etc. over the past few days and nothing has worked.
A slimmed down, compilable version of the current implementation is as follows:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
private let labelName: String = "Continue the conversation here..."
@State private var inputText: String = ""
@StateObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()
@State private var messages = ["Can you help me replace a broken phone?", "I'm ready, let's go to the first step", "(Step 1) Find the nearest Verizon store near you, typically located in a nearby mall or town center. Let me know when you've found it.", "Done", "(Step 2) Walk to the store that you've identified and enter the store. Read each new phone promotion to identify relevant features and potential discounts. Let me know when you are ready for the next step.", "Okay I am ready", "Great! Now for the phones that best fit your budget, spend some time playing around with them. Get a sense for the look and feel of the phone, and decide which one you like the most."]

var body: some View {
VStack{
    ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {                                      
                ForEach(Array(messages.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, message in
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                            Text(message)
                                .padding()
                                .cornerRadius(12)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: messages, initial: true) {
            scrollProxy.scrollTo(messages.count - 1, anchor: .bottom)
        }
        .onChange(of: keyboard.currentHeight) {
            scrollProxy.scrollTo(messages.count - 1, anchor: .bottom)
        }
        
    }
                                
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
        TextField(labelName, text: $inputText)
            .padding(8)
    }
}
}
}

where KeyboardResponder is
final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    var keyboardWillShowNotification = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
    var keyboardWillHideNotification = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)

    init() {
        keyboardWillShowNotification.map { notification in
            CGFloat((notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)!.height - 35)
        }
        .assign(to: \.currentHeight, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellableSet)

        keyboardWillHideNotification.map { _ in
            CGFloat(0)
        }
        .assign(to: \.currentHeight, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }

    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
}

Any ideas on what to do here? I have to imagine this is a fairly common implementation, but I am struggling to find a working solution online.
TIA!

Show some minimal code we can compile and run that produces your issue.
Note you should be using @StateObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()

@workingdogsupportUkraine thanks, I forgot how many random style constants I had in there. I updated the code above and it should now be compilable. Good catch on the StateObject piece, but that didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

As I understand it, this example may be helpful. Please give it a try.
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let messages = Message.dummyData
    @State private var tappedMessage: Message?
    @State private var newMessage = ""
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                    ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
                        MessageContainer(message: message)
                            .id(message.id)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tappedMessage = message
                                focus = true
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            if let tappedMessage {
                VStack {
                    TextEditor(text: $newMessage)
                        .frame(height: 80)
                        .padding()
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .focused($focus)
                    
                    Button("Send") { self.tappedMessage = nil }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.5) {
                        withAnimation {
                            scrollReader.scrollTo(tappedMessage.id)
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the reply Muhammad! The DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter does work as a workaround but it isn't smoothly transitioning the animation (i.e. the last message is often partially covered as the keyboard is presenting, but ends up snapping to the right place once the keyboard has fully presented). Any suggestions for how to make the animations occur simultaneously / not using asyncAfter?
